# cout repeats itself after getting user input

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am making a text based RPG, and I am having a little problem when I ask the user if they would like to play. The code works, when I answer with something I'm not supposed to answer with it tells me to answer with what im supposed to, and when I answer with a no it continues with closing the program. But when I enter yes the next cout gets read, but it then repeats the cout that came before it. Why is that? Thanks for the help.

Code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "mainMenu.h"
#include "heros.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

mainMenu::mainMenu() // Constructer
{

}

void mainMenu::mainMenuFunction()
{
cout << "Hello! Welcome to Dark Horse.\n";
cout << "In this game you start with making your 
hero.\n";
cout << "When you have made your desired choices, you 
will then start the actual game.\n";
cout << "Once you're in the game, you will go on an 
adventure to ______.\n";
cout << "I really hope you enjoy my little game. Let me 
know what you think on ";
cout << " Twitter! @Hoeins\n";

mainMenuChoice();
}

void mainMenu::mainMenuChoice()
{
char choice;

cout << "Would you like to play?\n";
cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y')
    {
        cout << "The game will now start.\n";
    }
    else if (choice == 'N' || choice == 'n')
    {
        cout << "The game will now close...\n";
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
    }
    else if (choice != 'N' && choice != 'n' && choice != 
'Y' && choice != 'y')
    {
        cout << "Enter Y or N\n";
        mainMenuChoice();
    }


}
```

Photo Previews: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSRRG.jpg

Comment: Please post your input-output examples as text, not images.

Comment: You are calling `mainMenuChoice()` recursively on bad input, so you see the same prompt again. I would suggest using a simple iterative loop instead, and break the loop on good input. Also, `else if (choice != 'N' && choice != 'n' && choice != 
'Y' && choice != 'y')` can be simplified to just `else`.

Comment: Alright thanks for the feedback! What exactly is an iterative loop? Also, what is good and bad input? I am still pretty new to programming, and still need to learn most terms.

Comment: Don't read a character when you want to read a line. That leads only to pain. When you ask the person if they want to play, you want to read in the line they enter. But you read only a character. *Don't do that!*

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you could try to use `while Statement` to implement an iterative loop.

> [Iteration
>   statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/iteration-statements-cpp?view=vs-2019)
>   cause statements (or compound statements) to be executed zero or more
>   times, subject to some loop-termination criteria. When these
>   statements are compound statements, they are executed in order, except
>   when either the break statement or the continue statement is
>   encountered.

Here is my code:

```
   char choice;

    cout << "Would you like to play?\n";
    cin >> choice;

    while (choice != 'N' && choice != 'n' && choice != 'Y' && choice != 'y')
    {
        cout << "Enter Y or N\n";
        cout << "Would you like to play?\n";
        cin >> choice;

    }

    if (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y')
    {
        cout << "The game will now start.\n";
    }
    else if (choice == 'N' || choice == 'n')
    {
        cout << "The game will now close...\n";
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the helpful answer! I had something like that earlier while trying to fix it but I was putting it in a do-while loop, and it was close but it wasn't giving me exactly what i was looking for. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured it out. I am sorry for this. It's my first time to actual work with classes and what not. Here is how I fixed it.

Main() Code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "gameStart.h"
#include "mainMenu.h"
#include "heros.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    mainMenu mainMenuObject;
    mainMenuObject.mainMenuIntro();

    mainMenu mainMenuChoiceObject;
    mainMenuChoiceObject.mainMenuChoice(); // I didn't post my main when I really should have. I apologize for that, but I noticed I had already called it here.

    gameStart gameStartObject;
    gameStartObject.gameStartFunction();


    heros herosObject;
    herosObject.heroFunction();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

mainMenuFunction() Code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "gameStart.h"
#include "mainMenu.h"
#include "heros.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

mainMenu::mainMenu() // Constructer
{

}

void mainMenu::mainMenuIntro()
{
    cout << "Hello! Welcome to Dark Horse.\n";
    cout << "In this game you start with making your hero.\n";
    cout << "When you have made your desired choices, you will then start the actual game.\n";
    cout << "Once you're in the game, you will go on an adventure to ______.\n";
    cout << "I really hope you enjoy my little game. Let me know what you think on ";
    cout << " Twitter! @Hoeins\n\n\n";
} // I removed the call here to mainMenuChoice()

void mainMenu::mainMenuChoice()
{
    char choice;
    bool i = false;

    cout << "Would you like to play?\n";
    cin >> choice;

    for (bool i = 0; i <= -1; i++)
    {
        if(choice == 'Y' || 'y')
        {
            cout << "Game will now start.\n";
            bool i = true;
            system("pause");
            gameStart();
        }
        else if(choice == 'N' || 'n')
        {
            cout << "Game will now close...\n";
            system("pause");
            exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Please enter a \"Y\" for yes, or an \"N\" for no.\n";
        }
    }
}
```

It now works fine! Thanks for the help!